# Fractional knapsack in C++11

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I am just picking up C++11 and decided to try some algorithmic problems to get better at it. One such problem is the fractional knapsack problem which can be solved by a greedy approach. The idea is to find the most valuable item and fill it in and move on to the next one till the knapsack is filled. Partial items are allowed.

I hope this code can be reviewed for:

- Correctness
- Correct usage of C++11 features
- Code logic improvement
- Coding conventions

```
struct Item {
    float value;
    float size;
    uint32_t index;
};

uint32_t FillKnapsack(std::vector<Item> &Items, const uint32_t MaxCap)
{
    // sorting is done based on value/size ratio of the item
    std::sort(Items.begin(),
              Items.end(),
              [](const Item& A, const Item& B) { return (A.value/A.size) > (B.value/B.size); });

    float c = 0, v = 0;

    for (const auto& item: Items) {
        if (c + item.size <= MaxCap) {
            c += item.size;
            v += item.value;
        }
        else {
            v += (MaxCap - c)/item.size * item.value;
            c = MaxCap;
        }

        std::cout << "adding item " << item.index << " with value " << item.value << std::endl;
        std::cout << "c: " << c << " v: " << v << std::endl;

        // since the knapsack is filled we can break out.  
        if (c >= MaxCap)
            break;
    }
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Item> items = { { 10, 30, 0},
                                { 20, 20, 1},
                                { 30, 10, 2} };
    std::cout << FillKnapsack(items, 35) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Return or Output

I feel like `FillKnapsack` should either (a) simply tell you the max value or (b) give you the items that it used. Right now, you're returning (a) and logging, incompletely, (b). (Incomplete because if you use a fractional amount of an item, that's not indicated).

I suggest you pick one or the other. If the former, basically just drop the `cout`s. If the latter, you'll want to return something like a:

```
std::vector<std::pair<Item, double>>
```

or:

```
struct ItemWithFraction {
    Item item;
    double fraction;
};
std::vector<ItemWithFraction>
```

#### Avoid single-letter variables

What is `c`? What is `v`?

#### Move the `break` into the branch

We have two cases per item: either we can fit the whole item and have room to spare, or we can't. If we can't, then we break. So that can become:

```
for (const auto& item : Items) {
    if (capacity + item.size < MaxCap) {
        value += item.value;
        capacity += item.size;
    }
    else {
        // last little bit left
        value += (MaxCap - capacity) / item.size * item.value;
        break;
    }
}
return value;
```

Don't need to assign `capacity` in the `else` case either.

#### Take items by copy

The idea of the algorithm suggests that given this set of items, find me a value. It doesn't suggest to me that you should reorder the items I pass in just because that happens to make it easier to solve the problem. To avoid being destructive, I'd write the signature as:

```
uint32_t FillKnapsack(std::vector<Item> Items, const uint32_t MaxCap)
```

If the user doesn't care, they can always `move()` the items in and avoid the copy.

#### Naming

Typically, `UpperCase` naming are used for classes (e.g. `Item`). Functions and variables are typically either `camelCase` (with the first letter lower) or `snake_case`. So I'd prefer

```
fillKnapsack(std::vector<Item> items, const uint32_t maxCapacity);
```

and

```
fill_knapsack(std::vector<Item> items, const uint32_t max_capacity);
```

to what you have.

Comment: Thanks. All the feedback is great. The updated code is on github: https://github.com/vivekian/cpp_practice/blob/master/modern_effective_cpp/chapter_6/fractional_knapsack.cpp

Answer (score 0):

As far as logic goes, there's a somewhat different approach that *might* be worth considering.

The (or at least *one*) basic problem with the code right now is that it always sorts *all* the input, regardless of how little it might actually need to use. At least in theory you could get some improvement by using `nth_element` to do a binary search for the correct number of elements to include.

For example, you'd start by finding the median of the inputs (with a descending comparison) and adding up the first half. If this is smaller than your target, subtract that from the total, and repeat the process on the right side of the array (without ever finishing sorting the left half, since we've already determined that it all needs to be included).

I'm somewhat uncertain, but I *believe* this works out to being \$O(N)\$ instead of \$O(N log N)\$ (in much the same way as nth_element itself, or quick-select in general end up linear--a logarithmic number of linear steps, each applied to a number of objects that's itself reducing logarithmically.